# Handle NSURLConnection connection issues

Tags: connection, nsurlconnection, httprequest, loading

The app we are making makes heavy use of HTTP requests, and therefore it is important that calls reach their destination. My question is, what is the best way to handle connection issues?

I want to avoid loading times and make as much as possible run in the background for instance when the player makes a virtual purchase or has to update his/her points on the server. Currently I am making a lot of loading screens that block everything until I am sure the call has gone through, and if it hasn't, then the user has to try again. Would there be a better way to handle this issue? for instance storing calls in a queue and if connection fails, the calls are being made in the correct order once connection has been established again?

Not sure what the best practice is, or if NSURLConnection has some build in features to handle issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can kick off NSURLConnection in a thread. Here is an [example](https://github.com/hrchen/ExamplesForBlog) if you want to use NSURLConnection directly.

Also you can try [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).